# Why is document.ready being called twice?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var page = 1;
  var notEOF = true;
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var temp = "string";
  client.open('GET', '/blog/blogdata.txt');
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (client.responseText != '') {
      var txt = client.responseText.split("\n");
      if (notEOF && txt[page * 6 - 6] != "EOF") {
        var data = txt[page * 6 - 6].split("@");
        document.getElementById("link1").setAttribute("href", data[0]);
        document.getElementById("image1").setAttribute("src", data[1]);
        document.getElementById("title1").innerHTML = data[2];
        document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = data[3];
        document.getElementById("tags1").innerHTML = data[4];
        document.getElementById("date1").innerHTML = data[5];
      } else {
        notEOF = false;
        $("#article1").hide();
      }
    }
  }
  var blog_html = "/blog/page";
  document.getElementById("prev").setAttribute("href", blog_html.concat((page - 1).toString()));
  document.getElementById("next").setAttribute("href", blog_html.concat((page - 1).toString()));
  if (page == 1) {
    $("#prev").addClass("disabled tm-mr-20");
  }
  if (page == 2) {
    document.getElementById("prev").setAttribute("href", "/blog/");
  }
  if (!notEOF) {
    $("#next").addClass("disabled tm-mr-20");
  }
  client.send();

});
```

```html
<script src="/blog/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/blog/js/templatemo-script.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This is a simplified version of a script I wrote in my blog html file to automate the blog part.

blog/blogdata.txt is a textfile consisting of lines of the form url@image url@title@text@tags@date, with the last line as just EOF. (If necessary, I can restructure this). This is the structure of a blog post (ripped from [here](https://templatemo.com/tm-553-xtra-blog))

```html
<article class="col-12 col-md-6 tm-post" id="article1">
  <hr class="tm-hr-primary">
  <a href="post.html" class="effect-lily tm-post-link tm-pt-60" id="link1">
    <div class="tm-post-link-inner">
      <img src="/blog/img/img-01.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid" id="image1">
    </div>
    <h2 class="tm-pt-30 tm-color-primary tm-post-title" id="title1">Simple and useful HTML layout</h2>
  </a>
  <p class="tm-pt-30" id="text1">
    There is a clickable image with beautiful hover effect and active title link for each post item. Left side is a sticky menu bar. Right side is a blog content that will scroll up and down.
  </p>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between tm-pt-45">
    <span class="tm-color-primary" id="tags1">Travel . Events</span>
    <span class="tm-color-primary" id="date1">June 24, 2020</span>
  </div>

</article>
```

And this is the structure of the previous and next buttons

```html
<div class="row tm-row tm-mt-100 tm-mb-75">
  <div class="tm-prev-next-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="mb-2 tm-btn tm-btn-primary tm-prev-next" id="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="mb-2 tm-btn tm-btn-primary tm-prev-next" id="next">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's obviously more to the script (if there's anything necessary I'm omitting, I'll add it) but this is the important part of it.

I'm trying to run the file but it's not functioning as intended (currently, the blogdata.txt file has one non-EOF line, and thus the blog should contain exactly one post. Instead, it contains none). When I added alerts to try to debug, I observed that this script is being called twice. Why?

Comment: Nothing in the code you've *shown* would indicate why this happens ... wondering what `$document` is though

Comment: WHY use XMLHttpRequest when you have $.get or $.ajax? You have jQuery, but you are not using it at all

Comment: `notEOF = false;`  and `if (!notEOF) ` arrgh

Comment: @Bravo page is a variable I'll modify on different pages, so... I get that it seems silly to write logic this way, but I prefer it to having to redesign my code every time I want a new page on my blog.

Comment: I'll share the whole code [here](https://github.com/rmehtany/rmehtany.github.io/blob/main/blog/index.html). Perhaps I am ignoring something obvious.

Comment: @mplungjan Again, it seems silly, until you see my whole code.

Comment: @Bravo Is it? I just think that editing one parameter is easier than changing code logic.

Comment: @Bravo How would you suggest doing it? (I have more than 6 copies, sadly).

Comment: @Bravo I made a transcription error. My bad. You can see my full code (I linked it somewhere).

Comment: is `var page = 1;` set by the server?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, but that's not relevant.

Comment: how do you know the code is being run twice?

Comment: Yes it is very relevant - so it IS some kind of paging.

Comment: @Bravo I have an alert in the code. If you want to see it in action, see [here](https://rmehtany.github.io/blog/)

Comment: @mplungjan For now, I'm setting it manually. I'll uncomment the server setting the page later.

Comment: @everyone I apologize for the poor code + dumb question, I really am trying to ask a good question here :(

Comment: just for testing, remove the `client.send();` I know the page will look wrong, but does the alert run twice still (by the way, I removed my irrelevant comments about the code - since that would not be the reason the alert runs twice)

Comment: @Bravo Checking now

Comment: @Bravo It now sends zero alerts. The script doesn't even run. I am so lost.

Comment: This is the weirdest

Comment: AH!   client.onreadystatechange = function() - you need to test it is done

Comment: @mplungjan If you want to see the full code, see [here](https://github.com/rmehtany/rmehtany.github.io/blob/main/blog/index.html). To see it run, see [here](https://rmehtany.github.io/blog/)

Comment: oh, its not weird at all now that I can see where the alert is happening - DONT use `onreadystatechange`, use `onload` (or run your code only when readystate is 4)

Comment: I told you to use $.get :)

Comment: @Bravo Sorry, could you explain that again? I'm slow with html/

Comment: @mplungjan Where should I use it?

Comment: `xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {`

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, trying it now

Comment: `xhr.onload = function() {` is better

Comment: The big problem here is you are treating an asynchronous call as if it is synchronous.  Second issue is you never look for the Ajax call is complete, onreadystatechange fires multiple times.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case

```
 client.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (client.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && client.responseText != '') {
```

but this is better

```
client.open('GET', '/blog/blogdata.txt');
client.onload = function() { ... }
client.send()
```

Since you have jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  var page = 1;
  var notEOF = true;
  var temp = "string";
  $.get('/blog/blogdata.txt', function(responseText) {
      if (!responseText || responseText.toString().trim() === "") return
      const txt = responseText.split("\n");
...

  });
});
```

Comment: Trying it out now. Will accept if it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: so, it's not the document ready called twice after all - that was the red herring!! it's the function in onreadystatechange that is called deveral times actually - P.S. never use alert for debugging

Comment: Ok, I'm running it with your modifications. It doesn't seem to be running the script at all. (I'm probably doing something very silly).

Comment: @Bravo How do you recommend debugging

Comment: console.log - by the way, did you put the `client.send()` back in the code?

Comment: @Bravo No I did not

Comment: well, that's why it's not running ... I told you to remove that for debugging - which helped spot where you were runnning alert

Comment: @Bravo Sorry :(

Comment: Code still has issues because it uses a variable in the asynchronous code!

Comment: @epascarello Could you explain that?

Comment: Yeah, you order a pizza and you try to eat it before it is delivered to your house. `notEOF = false;` is set inside the asynchronous call and will not be seen by the code after the onreadystatechange.

Comment: I added a wrapper for the jQuery $.get instead of your XmlHTTPRequest

Comment: @Bravo Works now. Thank you so much for your help. I'm really grateful to you and mplungjan

Comment: @mplungjan That looks a lot better than what I had! Thanks so much!

Comment: Still not correct.... but figure out that bug later. lol `if (!notEOF) {
    $("#next").addClass("disabled tm-mr-20");
  }` is never going to run

Comment: My fingers are itching to fix your parsing into something DRY

Comment: @epascarello How do I fix that? I see that's an issue

Comment: @mplungjan It's my first time writing js and html. I apologize for having to look at my dog**** code.

Comment: No need to apologise. JS is lovely when used appropriately...

Comment: @mplungjan Do you mind me asking slightly more general questions in a chatroom? It's really useful to learn from someone a lot more experienced.

Comment: I assume /blog/blogdata.txt will have several pages of events. Sounds like you are better off parsing it on the server if you are pagin on the server anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236089/discussion-between-don-thousand-and-mplungjan).